# NATS messaging : export issue

Tags: nats.io

I am exploring NATS for my project and stuck while adding exports. Despite '--private' flag is specified, the export is seen to be public when I describe it.

Here is a command I used to add export:

```
nsc add export -a TestCustomerAccount -n TestCustomerAccountExport -s "customers.TestCustomer.>" --private

$ ./nats-server --version
$ nats-server: v2.1.7
```

Could someone please help me? Doesn't it look to be a issue?

Thanks and Regards,
Prafulla

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. This was a minor defect. NATS team confirmed this and it is just a cosmetic defect with no impact on the actual functionality.